# Mostrar el contenido de un QList

Tags: c++, qt

Buenas, hace un tiempo que estoy trabajando con la librería Qt sobre C++ y se me esta presentando el siguiente problema:

Dada una clase denominadas "proyecto.h" defino una lista del siguiente modo `QList<Capa*> datosCapas;`.

Seguido de esto, procedo a cargar la lista de con el método `void addDataLayer (Capa* unaCapa);`. Básicamente lo que hace este método es lo siguiente

```
void proyecto::addDataLayer(Capa* unaCapaFromXml){
    this->datosCapas.append(unaCapaFromXml);
}
```

Al momento de querer imprimir por consola los datos, mediante un `qDebug()` y de esta manera asegurarme que en la lista se ha cargado los datos que necesito. Se me ocurrió implementar lo siguiente:

```
void proyecto:: imprimirLista(){
    QListIterator<Capa*> iteratorCapas(this->datosCapas);
    Capa objetoCapa;
    while(iteratorCapas.hasNext()){
      objetoCapa = iteratorCapas.next();
      qDebug() << objetoCapa.getH() << "|" << objetoCapa.getHNeta() << "|" << objetoCapa.getPorosity();
    }
}
```

El problema es que existe una incompatibilidad al momento de ir iterando la lista, justamente por que se trata de punteros.

```
error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'Capa' and 'Capa* const')
       objetoCapa = iteratorCapas.next();
                                   ^
```

¿Como debería trabajarlo y así poder imprimir los datos sin problemas?

> Pd: Si me preguntan por que agrego un puntero inteligente a la lista osea
>   (`Capa* unaCapaFromXml`)

se debe a que **unaCapaFromXml** es el parámetro que utilizo para alamacenar un objeto de tipo Capa, es decir en un momento del programa hago una instancia del objeto capa, osea  `new Capa(parámetro1,parámetro2,parámetro3)`.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

#### Problema.

Según leo en la [documentación de `QListIterator`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistiterator.html), la función [`next`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistiterator.html#next) tiene la siguiente firma:

```
const T &  next()
```

Según veo en tu código, tu lista es la siguiente:

```
QList<Capa*> datosCapas;
```

Es decir, guardas punteros a `Capa`. Y `next` devuelve una referencia al dato devuelto, así pues es como si tuviera esta firma:

```
const Capa *& next()
```

Devuelve una referencia a puntero, pero tú intentas guardarlo en un objeto `Capa` (no en un puntero a `Capa`):

```
//      vvvvvvvvvv <---- Instancia
   Capa objetoCapa;
// ^^^^ <---- Objeto
   while(iteratorCapas.hasNext()){
    //                            vvvv <---- Puntero
       objetoCapa = iteratorCapas.next();
    // ^^^^^^^^^^ <---- Instancia
```

#### Solución.

Usa un puntero:

```
void proyecto:: imprimirLista(){
    QListIterator<Capa*> iteratorCapas(this->datosCapas);
      // vvvvvvvvvvvv <---- Puntero
    Capa *punteroCapa;
    while(iteratorCapas.hasNext()){
     //                             vvvv <---- Puntero
        punteroCapa = iteratorCapas.next();
     // ^^^^^^^^^^^ <---- Puntero
        qDebug() << objetoCapa.getH() << "|" << punteroCapa->getHNeta() << "|" << punteroCapa->getPorosity();
     //                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^ <----- Puntero -----> ^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
}
```

#### Alternativa.

Des-referencia antes de usar:

```
void proyecto:: imprimirLista(){
    QListIterator<Capa*> iteratorCapas(this->datosCapas);
    while(iteratorCapas.hasNext()){
     //                    v <---- Des-referenciar.
        Capa &objetoCapa = *iteratorCapas.next();
     // ^^^^^^ <---- Referencia           ^^^^ <---- Puntero
        qDebug() << objetoCapa.getH() << "|" << objetoCapa.getHNeta() << "|" << objetoCapa.getPorosity();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola, me sirvió tu solución, pero igual sigo teniendo un problema con ambas soluciones. Paso a comentarte: Con la solucion1 me imprime lo siguiente **0.28 100 5 30 30 4400** segunda iteracion **3.0666e-41 | 100 | 5 | 30 | 30 | 4400**. Para la segunda solución imprime bien, pero intuyo que hay un problema cuando se trata de valores realeas, para los enteros los imprime sin problemas **4.56095e-41 | -2.07975e-17 | 3.09575e-41 | 30 | 30 | 4400** segunda iteracion **3.09575e-41 | 1 | 5 | 30 | 30 | 4400**

Comment: Por las dudas, me olvide de aclararte que por iteracion se imprime 6 valores, ya que decidí imprimir todos los atributos del objeto capa que se encuentran almacenados en `this->datosCapas`

Comment: Sin conocer la implementación de `Capa`, no puedo más que intentar adivinar (no resolver) tu problema. Es como si no hubieras inicializado las variables internas de los objetos alojados en tu `QList`.

Answer (score 0):

Creo importante comentar que `QList` no es una lista enlazada propiamente dicha, tal y como indica [la documentación](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#details). La lista enlazada de Qt es la [`QLinkedList`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlinkedlist.html). Más bien, `QList` es un vector modificado:

> Internally, QList is represented as an array of T if sizeof(T) <= sizeof(void*)

Ahora bien, el uso de iteradores con `QList` puede ser sustituido por alguna de las siguientes formas:

1. `Q_FOREACH` (obsoleto desde Qt 5.7):

   ```
   Q_FOREACH (auto capa, this->datosCapas) {
     // 'capa' es de tipo 'Capa*'
   }
   ```
2. Equivalente si usas C++11:

   ```
   for (auto capa : this->datosCapas) {
     // 'capa' es de tipo 'Capa*'
   }
   ```
3. Un bucle iterando los índices manualmente:

   ```
   for (int ii = 0; ii < this->datosCapas.count(); ++ii) {
     this->datosCapas[ii]-> ...;
   }
   ```